# Is it good to take a project even if the topic is not what I'm interested?

Tags: career-path, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

One of my university professors offered me a research assistant position which would require me to study for a master degree.

I really wanted to take it but there are few problems for me.

1. I don't know that professor.
2. I don't know what career I could take after finishing a master degree.
3. I feel like other people are able to make more money early. (Even if I don't care about money).
4. Money problem mostly because I still need find a job to support myself.

Even though it got a full fee waiver, I couldn't change the research topic for the whole master degree.

So I guess my question is should I really take it even though I'm not really interested in that particular project and worried about my future career.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a LOT of negatives in addition to the one in the title even.

Just responding to the one in the title, I would say to do a project that interests you.  Of course be smart about not picking something that involves a jerk advisor, unlikely to work, or 10 years of apparatus building or waiting for next Space Shuttle (even if you like the topic).  But in general, pick something you like.

That one looks like a dud.  Go talk to several more professors.  Have fun scheduling some meetings and talking to them.  Many of them like talking about their stuff and will pitch you on something or even mention a few possibilities.  You need to get a few options in front of you and choose the best one.  For one thing running this process will show you what is available and help you compare by contrast.  Don't marry the first girl you date.  Well, except I should have, but she was special!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

While in general it is a (very) good idea to explore new things, the negatives you list seem to imply that it is premature for you to do this. Committing to a Masters degree on a project that you aren't especially interested in seems like a bad idea.

On the other hand, if money is a small concern for you and time is of little or no concern, it might be worth it for the experience.

Spend some time thinking about what you really want your future to look like and evaluate whether a project like this fits in some way. Don't take a side trip just because the opportunity is there. Think about the main route to your future.

The fact that you don't know the professor is of little concern (or should be). You could explore things with that professor, of course: "What would my future look like if I do this?". Such an exploration would also let you know a bit more about the professor. If s/he isn't willing to spend time with you on this, you have learned something important, of course.